# SSRS output to Word formatting issue

Tags: ms-word, formatting, export, ssrs-2008

I have a 2008 SSRS Report that is being export to as MS Word doc using the standard Export functionality provided by the SSRS tool.  Even though the data on the report is textual in nature and resides in text boxes, the Export is rendering the text using tables.  This formatting is too cumbersome for the users.  Is ther a way to adjust how an MS Word is rendered using the SSRS Export functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is ther a way to adjust how an MS Word is rendered using the SSRS Export functionality?

No

Answer (score 5):

The regular export can be pretty ugly. [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-for-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx) has export functionality that can be a bit prettier. If you need a ton of control over the style of the resulting word documents you should take a look at it.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the engineers who built the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

MS word and SSRS are like the long lost friends still trying to figure out things on rendering. One way I dealt with this problem is to make sure there is a master tablix and the rows are filled with the tablix calls the information to be displayed and aligned. If there is any sort of information to be displayed together  place a different tablix and try to avoid using the row visibility which have heavy chance to leave empty space when rendered to word.

And there are chances of the header and footer to be truncated. To solve this place a text box above the entire header and below the footer make sure the textbox font color is white to hide the textbox.